# Run http service synchronously

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I will get some response from below code:

```
this.http.post("http://localhost/angular5/user-add.php", this.myform.value, {responseType: 'json'}).subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(data)
            }
        )
```

After getting the result, I need to run below code:

```
this.http.post("http://localhost/angular5/user.php", formData).subscribe(
            imageData => {
                console.log(imageData)
            }
        )
```

I need to run this code synchronously. How to make it synchronous? Now the secondary code is not waiting for the primary code.

Comment: You need to look into the RxJS operators, in this case `flatMap` or `switchMap`, to start the second request after the first has completed.

Comment: thanks for the response. I need to run second call multiple times. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but depending on the behaviour you need different approaches will be most appropriate. Hence the suggestion that you do more research on what's available within RxJS, so you better understand those approaches.

Comment: "I need to run second call multiple times." Does the data _change between calls?_ If not, look into `.share()` or `.replay()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest is probably `async`/`await`, without getting into Rx territory (you might not wanna delve in there).

```
async doSomething() {
   const req1 = await this.http.post("http://localhost/angular5/user-add.php", this.myform.value, {responseType: 'json'}).pipe(first()).toPromise();

   const req2 = await this.http.post("http://localhost/angular5/user.php", formData).pipe(first()).toPromise();

   console.log(req1, req2);
}
```

The `async` keyword basically makes the function-body behave like its synchronous.
It will always return a promise, so you might need to `await doSomething()`.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, it is clear that you need to post second request (user) after first post response (useradd)

Since http.post returns an observable, instead of subscribing to this directly, you may chain the first observable to second observable and subscribe to that instead. switchMap (or flatMap) seems to be the operator you need.

Something like this:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const firstRequest = this.http.post("http://localhost/angular5/user-add.php", this.myform.value, {responseType: 'json'});

const secondRequest = switchMap( data => {
    console.log(data); //First request data. Chain it to second request.
    return this.http.post("http://localhost/angular5/user.php", formData);
});

const combinedRequest = secondRequest(firstRequest);

combinedRequest.subscribe(imageData => console.log(imageData));
```

Note that first request won't be fired until you call subscribe on the combinedRequest

Comment: I'd opt for `switchMap` over `flatMap` as a rule of thumb, for observables that only emit once, or emit in a predictable fashion.

Comment: Yes, for this example, switchMap seems better. Editing answer to use switchMap. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the asynchronous code synchronous. What you can do is delay the execution of the second request until the first one returns.

Somebody in the comments suggested using `flatMap` or `switchMap`, but it doesnt't look like the second request will use the value returned by the first one. If this is the case, a simple `concat` should work.

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs/observable';

const addUser$ = this.http.post(
    "http://localhost/angular5/user-add.php", 
    formValue, 
    {responseType: 'json'}
);

const postUser$ = this.http.post("http://localhost/angular5/user.php", formData);

// addUser$ will execute first, than postUser$
concat(addUser$, postUser$)
  .subscribe(// ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert your observable to a function and use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
async yourMethod()
{
    //first call
    let data = await this.http.post("http://localhost/angular5/user-add.php", this.myform.value, {responseType: 'json'}).toPromise();
    console.log(data);

    //2nd call - executes after the first one
    this.http.post("http://localhost/angular5/user.php", formData).subscribe(
        imageData => {
            console.log(imageData)
        }
    )
}
```